# AWS Lambda: capture the return value of Lambda in Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda that checks if AWS EC2 configurations are present in an AWS account. I have invoked this lambda as part of an stack execution (this is an Cloud formation template).

Now the **Lambda** invoked will ***return a json string*** as a response/return value. How to save/capture this response in a Calling CFN template and fetch the value in the Dictionary and use this value as a Condition variable in the Cloud Formation template further?

Invoking lambda:

```
CheckEc2ConfigsLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: Lambda to return ec2 instances.
      FunctionName: !Sub "abc-lambda-${AWS::Region}"
      Code:
        S3Bucket: "{{resolve:ssm:/abc/abc-bucket}}"
        S3Key: !Sub "abc_lambda/${BuildId}/abc_lambda.zip"
      Handler: abc_lambda.lambda_handler
      PackageType: Zip
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: 
        "Fn::GetAtt": ["AbcLambdaRole", "Arn"]
      Runtime: python3.8
      Timeout: 900
```

Now the lambda `abc_lambda` returns a *Json String*, How can we capture this Json string in the above lambda invoker for further processing ?

[I was exploring Output option in Cloud Formation but not sure if that would match the need here.]

Comment: Use a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is not accurate to say you "invoked this lambda as part of an stack execution" in the CloudFormation snippet you shared.  That snippet may have *created* the lambda during the stack execution, but it did not *invoke* it.

To invoke a lambda and use the result, you should use a custom resource.  [This example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html) walks through how one might be used.  In step 2 it shows a CloudFormation snippet that creates the lambda function, similar to your snippet above.  Then it shows another resources that *invokes* the function and uses the result in this section:

```
AMIInfo:
  Type: Custom::AMIInfo
  Properties:
    ServiceToken: !GetAtt AMIInfoFunction.Arn
    Region: !Ref "AWS::Region"
    Architecture:
      Fn::FindInMap:
      - AWSInstanceType2Arch
      - !Ref InstanceType
      - Arch
```

So you would need to do something like in that example.